# Phonegap restart accelerometer

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, accelerometer

I'm facing problems restarting the accelerometer in a Phonegap app.
What I am trying to achieve is to watch the acceleration. After the user moved the smartphone I want to stop the watcher, do some animations, etc. and after 500ms to 1s I'd like to start the watcher again.

This basically is the code for the accelerometer:

```
watchAcceleration: function() {
    this.accelerometerID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(
    function(acceleration) {
        console.log("STARTED WATCH");

        // Accelerometer calculations going on here ...

        if(this.direction === correctResponse) {
            this.restartAcceleration();
        }
        else {
            alert("FAIL");
        }

        // ... more accelerometer calculations here
    }.bind(this),
    function(err) {
        console.log("error", err)
    }
}
```

Here's the code of the restart function:

```
restartAcceleration: function() {
    if(this.accelerometerID) {
        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(this.accelerometerID);
        this.accelerometerID = null;
        console.log("WATCH CLEARED");
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.watchAcceleration();
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when the app starts the accelerometer works perfectly. When the user responds correctly the restartAcceleration function is invoked and the watcher cleared. After the 1000ms in this case the watchAcceleration function is invoked again.

My phone is a Nexus 4.
Do you have any suggestions on how to restart the accelerometer correctly?

Edit (July 4th, 2016):
An issue was filed here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11531

Comment: Have you verified that `this` is correct in setTimeout callback? Also, what is exact behavior - doesn't `STARTED WATCH` shows the second time?

Comment: @daserge - Thanks for your reply. The context of `this` is correct. The string `STARTED WATCH` does not appear the second time. Output to the console above the line where the `watchAcceleration`function is called is printed. So it seems that the callback of watch acceleration is not called anymore...

Comment: does it have the same issue if you deploy the device-motion plugin tests (there are manual tests for watch/clear)? Does the issue reproduce on emulator or other devices? What is your device Android OS version?

Comment: Hi @daserge! Well, I do not know how to deploy the device-motion plugin tests, but I can now confirm that it works with a Samsung Galaxy S3 w/ Android 4.4.2 (the original Samsung Rom). The phone which does not work is a Nexus4 w/ Android 6.0.1 (CyanogenMod 13).

Comment: consider filling an issue on issues.cordova.io

Comment: @jcesarmobile: Ok, I'll file an issue there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug in the plugin - try using this PR branch:

- `git clone -b CB-11531 https://github.com/daserge/cordova-plugin-device-motion`
- `cd app`
- `cordova plugin rm device-motion`
- `cordova plugin add ../cordova-plugin-device-motion`

Comment: this PR branch works as expected. So the master branch of the plugin should work either. Thanks for fixing this bug!

Comment: the bug still exists in the NPM module. I was also experiencing the bug again in the master branch (thought it was already merged). But now I see that it is not yet merged into the master

Comment: npm update will occur on plugins release. Hmm, it [has been merged](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion/commit/293dcb9220ac379a9e4cd7776d02969367df6dca). Are you trying the master branch like this `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion`?

Comment: nope, I cloned the repository with `git clone https://github.com/daserge/cordova-plugin-device-motion` and tried to add the plugin with `phonegap plugin add ../cordova-plugin-device-motion` like before with the bugfix branch. but your suggested solution (adding the plugin directly via the github link) works perfectly. thanks again! ;)